# Idle postgres connections are not closing

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using node-postgres pool and i have set idleTimeoutMillis, but idle connections are not closing and they are stacking up.

```
const {Pool} = require('pg')
pool = new Pool({
                connectionString: process.env.PG_HOST,
                ssl: false,
                max: 20,
                idleTimeoutMillis: 1000,
                connectionTimeoutMillis: 20000,
            });

    let client;
    try {
            client = await pool.connect()
            await client.query(sqlQuery)
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
        } finally {
            if(client)
                client.release()
        }
```

#### Though I have released connection in many places in my code, there were few places where I had not closed the connection. So the idle connection are stacking up. However after idleTimeoutMillis connections should have been terminated, but they are not getting terminated.

Comment: Are you checking you connections back into the pool?  Can you show a more complete example?

Comment: @jjanes, i have updated question

Comment: From the perspective of the pool, a connection that is not returned is not idle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But when i check pg_stat_activity table those connections are idle. Is there a way to clean up unreleased connections after some time through code?

Comment: As I said: the pool does not know that. And the pool's perception of "idle" is something different than Postgres' "idle". It's the pool that physically closes those connections when **the pool** thinks the connections are idle (from its perspective). You need to make sure that **all** unused connections are returned properly to pool. This is a bug in your application. Fix that rather than trying ugly workarounds in other layers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then when i remove idleTimeoutMillis field from config why unreleased connections listed as idle in pg_stat_activity?

Comment: Again: because the pools idea of "idle" is something completely different than Postgres' idea of "idle"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry there was mistake in my previous comment, when i remove idleTimeoutMillis field from config unreleased connections are not listed as idle in pg_stat_activity